# Find results by string in related documents

Tags: solr

I have an Solr Database with those documents:

```xml
<doc>
    <str name="document_name_s">comment</str>
    <int name="deal_id_i">1</int>
    <int name="forumuser_id_i">8</int>
    <str name="id">108</str>
    <str name="message_s">hi kone you are right...</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="document_name_s">comment</str>
    <int name="deal_id_i">1</int>
    <int name="forumuser_id_i">8</int>
    <str name="id">112</str>
    <str name="message_s">41lxlg9x abbiiiog 1rkrp 440s 7hm34 4vyvg7t wevo bmq 718am5 d3d609 zxjrkd ycklykhx 1xasj v307287</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="document_name_s">deal</str>
    <str name="content_s">o2tqtoc3ge ryjf tti ed3rr6 r1vw4wla1c 3lmu7 o72ee1fmd jv7dcn usao0 iuz cy4s91 ys52w3t 8td2hz2pgu 58pxad6l zsyov07p r2z2 doav4k u1i49k c0te79k wrdkbqkr eo8p8e0ez 65u 3syi zu870a k3pl p4v zrjurlsa3 ivg v1h00 nfhx ujcxx3 mf46s xkld0fh mkeexbyb sqpq udncpnd0 uz0922dmmj vqwn zf59gl0rc 3tn z98n kql9ry1p 02gk 0rff5lt hb0exi9cp olik492q 4ycl c9ma2zx uwghjavut2 sczpmlg qqpy tqptp5h k5qce2pj ntv 5u98bg58n mshyy8e m7ip0m m7gd8z343 a99df fhp5g5ny 51vg3mxm cfk7au mmf67x0cj hrh 7i16 0mxzaq97 ca9o 5g0ct p0b hf6h3 e9ghhrjlt dqjj x1v9 ko3a5i hoq1 44k jfhf 121bsb6ud3 cql6l ipirv2 6qhpjcb 25t0zm67 ttm5lt</str>
    <int name="forumuser_id_i">1</int>
    <str name="id">1</str>
    <str name="plainlink_s">http://www.zalando.de/adidas-performance-dfb-pu-messenger-core-green-white-ad544a0e0-602.html</str>
    <str name="title_s">g4c Schuhe vtklq50</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="document_name_s">forumuser</str>
    <str name="id">1</str>
    <str name="username_s">kone2</str>
</doc>
```

Now i want to find all "deals" where for example user "kone" is the user of the deal, or where the comment text contains "kone" as word. Is this possible in Apache Solr 4?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a **Join** query. The syntax is described in the **[Solr 4.0 documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join)**. I guess the first example is already what you want, so this should work:

```
q={!join from=forumuser_id_i to=id}kone
```

The only change compared to a "normal" query is the specification of the join relationship:

```
q={!join from=... to=...}...
```

This allows you to further limit your results, for example by using a filter query (`fq`) to only return "deals".

Comment: What i dont understand is how to join multiple types. So how would it look if you integrate th search in the comments in your example.

Answer (score 1):

What you effectively want to achieve here is JOIN between different documents.

Unfortunately, this feature is only available starting from [Solr 4.0](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join).

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question to ask for an query in solr 4. Do you have an idear how a query would look for solr 4?

Comment: I believe Daniel has already provided an answer, there's nothing much for I could add.